# Jquery history.go(-1); não funciona Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Já fiz umas pesquisas até mesmo aqui no stackoverflow sobre criar um botão voltar. 
A situação é que eu clico em um registro dinâmico para editar, depois tenho a opção de Cancelar (que é para voltar) no IEca e FF funciona, mas no chrome temos problema.

Já tentei outras alternativas, mas nada deu certo continua a não funcionar.

```
<button type="submit" name="voltar" value="voltar" id="voltar" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 30px">Cancelar</button>


    $('#voltar').click(function() {

        history.go(-1);
        return false;
    });
```

Já tentei algo direto inline também em JS, mas não deu! Alguma solução ?

SOLUÇÃO:
Aparentemente o que fiz para dar certo foi só tirar o jquery que estava no final da página e jogar no começo da mesma. Vai entender.

Comment: Esse botão é gerado dinamicamente por javascript/jquery?

Comment: Isso funciona no chrome, acredito que o que deve estar errado é como você vai para a tela de edição. Se for via ajax, lembre-se que é você quem deve [manipular o history do browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: Onde o js postado está? Em um script separado? Na própria página?

Comment: Kadu não é não.. é um html normal.

Comment: Guilherme o código js/jquery está na mesma página é tudo simples mesmo!

Comment: Não existe ajax não, eu simplesmente pego registro (pelo id) e levo a outra página e faço edição dos dados.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um teste com o seu código da seguinte forma do Chrome e funcionou normalmente:

```
<button type="submit" name="voltar" value="voltar" id="voltar" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 30px">Cancelar</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#voltar').click(function() {

        history.go(-1);
    return false;
});
</script>
<a href="teste.html?a">link</a>
```

De qualquer forma tente remover o return false, caso ele esteja interrompendo alguma ação da sua página.

**OBS:** Fique atento se realmente existe alguma página no history para voltar, pois o -1 só volta para a posição anterior, e se for para a mesma, em alguns casos ele ignora, sugiro que coloque um link para a página neste caso (como em breadcrumbs).

Abs